# Spring Boot - How to test that Model attribute was added from configuration file?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a controller which adds attributes from `application.properties` to a `Model` object:

```
@Value("${products}")
private String prod;

@GetMapping("/")
public String greetingForm(Model model) throws IOException {

    List<String> products = Arrays.asList(prod.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

    model.addAttribute("products",products);

    return "form";
}
```

How can I test this method? I'm fairly new to unit testing so any advice would be appreciated. I know I have to mock `Model` somehow but every time I try to run my test, I get a `NullPointerException`.

My test:

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private Model model;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new WebController()).build();
}



@Test
public void testHomeRoute() {

        try {

            List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
            products.add("Product1");
            products.add("Product2");

            mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("form"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("products",products));
                ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that a copy of application.properties is in your src/test/resources folder to make sure unit tests pick up these properties.

Also make sure your test class is annotated with `@SpringBootTest` so that the relevant configuration for loading properties is loaded into your tests.

EDIT: You also don't want to call new on your Controller here:

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new WebController()).build();
```

By instatiating it yourself it is no longer a Spring bean and the @Value annotation will not be correctly injected into this class for you. Instead you should autowire your Controller in and use this to build your MockMvc.

```
@Autowired
private WebController webController;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(webController).build();
}
```